# How to check if a command is running currently?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, ps

I want to check if a command is running with the following `if` clause, but it's always `true`, whether command actually is running or not:

```
if [ $"(ps aux | grep curl)" ]; then echo is; else echo not; fi
```

Result:

```
[root@is ~]# if [ $"(ps aux | grep curl)" ]; then echo is; else echo not; fi
is
```

The `ps` command outside of `if`:

```
[root@is ~]# ps aux | grep curl
root      216564  0.0  0.2   6408  2064 pts/0    S+   22:22   0:00 grep --color=auto curl
```

How can I check if `curl` in my example is running or not?

I tried with different arguments of `ps`, but I always have the `grep` command (which is normal in my mind), but I don't know how to check that if it's running or not.

**Update 1**

I'm thinking that I can do this but I don't know how to do this in commands:

```
if ps aux blah
  if it has only one line (I suppose somehow use `wc -l`
    then do something
  else do something else
  fi
fi
```

Comment: What would you consider to show it to be running? Using CPU? Generating network traffic?

Comment: Use another `grep` to filter the first `grep`

Comment: @AndrewMorton my application first `curl`s a site and downloads a file, then updates the database. I use it in `cron` and I don't want to run multiple downloads at the same time and slowing my network bandwidth.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I think the exit status of `if [ $"(ps aux | grep curl | grep site)" ]; then echo is; else echo not; fi` is always 0 because even this command works as `true`.

Comment: Which Linux distro? Doesn't `pgrep curl` just work for you?

Comment: @Destroy666 I use CentOS 9 Stream. `pgrep curl` works and I tried with both running `curl` and killing PID. Thanks. Please write it as an answer.

Comment: I mean `ps aux | grep curl | grep -v grep`

Comment: I think `pgreg curl` is shorter than `ps aux | grep curl | grep -v grep`. But Thanks for the comment and answer.

Answer (score 11):

You can just use `pgrep curl`, which returns process ID(s) only if a running process is found. Example:

```
[  -n "$(pgrep curl)" ] &&  echo "yes" || echo "no"
```

[pgrep documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html)

Answer (score 8):

The common trick to skip the line with the grep itself is to use some kind of a regex:

```
ps aux | grep '[c]url'
```

The commmand itself now doesn't contain the string `curl` itself, so it won't match.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is to add another `grep` to filter the `grep` process
instead of

```
ps aux | grep curl
```

make it

```
ps aux | grep curl | grep -v grep
```

Comment: ... unless you're curl'ing something served by http://grep.example.org.

Comment: @asdfex, in such case i will grep `grep.example.com` :)